# function does not always return a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make this ajax request function work but netbeans is giving a warning that the following function does not always return a value. Can anyone please help.

```
function fpform(){
    var response='';
    var fpemail = $('#frgtpwd').val();
    //var fpemail = document.getElementById('frgtpwd').value;

    if (fpemail == ""){
        $('span#fperror').text("insert your emal address");
        //document.getElementById('fperror').innerHTML = "Insert your email address";
        return false;
    } else {
        var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        if (filter.test(fpemail)==false) { 
            $('span#fperror').text("Email address is not in valid format");
            //document.getElementById('fperror').innerHTML = "Email address is not in valid format";
            return false;
        } else {
            $("#loader").html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $.post("forgot_password_process.php", {
                email:fpemail
            }, function(response){
                response = response.trim();
            }).success(function () {
                if (response == 'yes'){
                    $("#fperror").html('<font color="green"><b>Your password has been reset now and emailed to you </b></font>');
                    $("#loader").hide('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
                    return true;
                } else {
                    alert("your email address was not found");
                    $("#loader").hide('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
                    $("#fperror").html('<font color="black"><b> Email address was not found in database!</b></font>');
                    return false;
                } 
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return true;` statement in your code is not returning from `fpform`. It is instead returning from the callback function given to `.success()`. By the time this function is executed, the outer function, `fpform`, has long since returned. The only way to "return" from a function using ajax is with a callback.

---

Before I give you any code, you've made a bunch of other mistakes:

1. Your email regex, `/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/`, fails on my email address. `+` is a valid character as well. Consider [not validating email addresses with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/102441).
2. `$("#loader").hide('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />')` does not work. At all. You want `$("#loader").empty()`
3. The variable `response` you declare at the top is shadowed by your argument `response` in one of your anonymous functions, making `response = response.trim()` have no effect whatsoever.

---

```
function fpform(callback) {
    var fpemail = $('#frgtpwd').val();

    if (fpemail == ""){
        $('span#fperror').text("insert your email address");
        callback(false);
    } else {
        var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        if (filter.test(fpemail)==false) { 
            $('span#fperror').text("Email address is not in valid format");
            callback(false);
        } else {
            $("#loader").html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $.post("forgot_password_process.php", {
                email:fpemail
            }).success(function(response) {
                response = response.trim();
                if (response == 'yes'){
                    $("#fperror").html('<font color="green"><b>Your password has been reset now and emailed to you </b></font>');
                    $("#loader").hide('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
                    callback(true);
                } else {
                    alert("your email address was not found");
                    $("#loader").hide('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
                    $("#fperror").html('<font color="black"><b> Email address was not found in database!</b></font>');
                    callback(false);
                } 
            }).error(function() { callback(false); });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return value after `$.post(...).success(...);`